# Can an age or a difference between two dates be represented linearly?

Tags: functions, soft-question, calendar-computations

I've found an interesting answer on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11942/11808605) when it comes to calculating someone's age based on that person's date of birth and the date at which the age is calculated. The calculation is something like this:

$A_{fraction} = \frac{\Delta Y\cdot{10^4} + \Delta M\cdot{10^2} + \Delta D}{10^4}$
$\iff A=\left \lfloor A_{fraction} \right \rfloor$

With $A$ being the age and where $\Delta Y$ is the difference in years, $\Delta M$ is the difference in months and $\Delta D$ is the difference in days between the two dates.

I tried to extend this idea of taking differences up to smaller time intervals, so I went down to the millisecond like so:

$A_{fraction} = \frac{\Delta Y\cdot{10^{13} + \Delta M\cdot{10^{11} + \Delta D\cdot{10^9} + \Delta H\cdot{10^7} + \Delta m\cdot{10^5} + \Delta s\cdot{10^3} + \Delta \mu}}}{10^{13}}$

But instead of rounding the age down, I decided to keep its fractional part and plot it against various dates of birth, and this happened:

[image: Age plot]

*Plot of the results of the fractional age calculation for $10^4$ equally spaced dates between 17 December 1993 and 8 March 2021.* [raw data](https://controlc.com/c8b24c4a)

Which seemed rather counter-intuitive to me. I expected that a graph with steps would arise from the floored age calculation, but I thought the more granular fractional age calculation would show something closer to a straight line. It doesn't seem like it has something to do with leap years, because it steps down annually instead of every four years.

So, here's my question: is it possible to find a formula that can linearly map a date of birth (e.g. 17 December 1993) when calculated at a particular date (e.g. 8 March 2021) to its corresponding age ($\approx 27$)?

### Barry's formula visualized

Graph for $A = \Delta Y + \frac{\Delta M}{12} + \frac{\Delta D}{30}$

[image]

Same graph but zoomed between (January 1994 and July 1996)

[image]

Comment: The formula $\Delta Y+(\Delta M/12)+(\Delta D/30)$ should give a better approximation than what amounts to $\Delta Y+(\Delta M/100)+(\Delta D/10000)$.

Comment: @BarryCipra This is what the [graph](https://imgur.com/a/58iYJIz) of your expression looks like, it's pretty cool but unfortunately still not a straight line as you can see from this [zoomed version](https://imgur.com/a/OUCnhds).

Comment: Sorry, for some reason the images are not viewable for me. If you can edit them into your question, that'd be great. In any event, I wouldn't expect an exact straight line since not every month has exactly $30$ days. (If they did, there'd be just $360$ days in a year.)

Comment: @BarryCipra that's a good point, I suppose I'm trying to map each age to some regular time interval, like a day or an hour or a second, and find a way to map that to dates as we know them. I've also updated my question to include visualisations of your formula.

Comment: Oh dear, my formula is quite wrong in the coefficient for days. It shoud be $\Delta D/365$ (or at least $\Delta D/360$), not $\Delta D/30$.  Silly me.